# Aeron cluster nodes failed to join and throw timeout exception

Tags: java, cluster-computing, messaging, lmax, aeron

We have an Aeron cluster with three nodes, after starting the cluster two of the nodes throw the following error on startup. Because we take a snapshot from states, they should load the snapshot first.

Consensus Module

```
io.aeron.exceptions.TimeoutException: WARN - failed to join live log

at io.aeron.cluster.Election.followerLogAwait(Election.java:1041)

at io.aeron.cluster.Election.doWork(Election.java:219)

at io.aeron.cluster.ConsensusModuleAgent.doWork(ConsensusModuleAgent.java:344)

at org.agrona.concurrent.AgentRunner.doWork(AgentRunner.java:304)

at org.agrona.concurrent.AgentRunner.workLoop(AgentRunner.java:296)

at org.agrona.concurrent.AgentRunner.run(AgentRunner.java:162)

at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.